# JavaFx; Label Center depend on width

Tags: javafx, label

i have *Pane* and *Label* on it.
How to set *layoutXProperty* of *Label* so that it would be in Center on X line?
I think i should use formula like this: (Pane.width-Label.width)/2
But i don't know how it write right. And i have not found answer in google.

Can some one hint me?
thxs.

Upd. Text of the Label i update after if declaration, and it text can be different length. So i want to set *layoutXProperty* to it depend on length of text and would be on CENTER.

UPD: code inserted

```
public void start(Stage myStage) throws FileNotFoundException {

        myStage.setTitle("OrthographyChecker");

        Pane pane = new Pane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 700, 300);


        Label labelUp = new Label();
        labelUp.setFont(new Font(fontSize));
        labelUp.layoutXProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty().subtract(labelUp.widthProperty()).divide(2));
        labelUp.layoutYProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty().subtract(labelUp.heightProperty()).divide(5));
        labelUp.setText("Click to start");
        pane.getChildren().addAll(labelUp);

        TextField inputTxt = new TextField("");
        inputTxt.setVisible(false);
        inputTxt.layoutXProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty().subtract(inputTxt.widthProperty()).divide(2));
        inputTxt.layoutYProperty().bind(labelUp.layoutYProperty().add(35));
        pane.getChildren().addAll(inputTxt);

        Label chkL = new Label("");
        chkL.setFont(new Font(fontSize));
        chkL.layoutYProperty().bind(inputTxt.layoutYProperty().add(30));
        chkL.layoutXProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty().subtract(chkL.widthProperty()).divide(2));
        chkL.setStyle("-fx-border-color: blue;");
        pane.getChildren().addAll(chkL);

        inputTxt.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {
                try {
                    for (String OneWrd : chkWrd[0].replace(", ", ",").split(",")) {
                        if (inputTxt.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(OneWrd)) {
                            chkL.setText("You are right!");
                            chkL.setVisible(true);
                            notfound[0] = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (notfound[0]){
                        chkL.setText("Wrong! Right answer: \"" + chkWrd[0] + "\"");
                        chkL.setVisible(true);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    errPrint(e, "Установки ожидания ");
                }
                inputTxt.setText("");
                pause[0] = false;
                notfound[0] = true;
                chkL.layoutXProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty().subtract(labelUp.widthProperty()).divide(2));
            }
        });


        myStage.setScene(scene);
        myStage.show();
    }
```

It part of code, which use it trouble label (variable **chkL**). As you can see, i have binded it to center, like another Label. But this label changes alingment after first iteration of change text of label, and starts to looks like [that screen (label in border)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqoeS.png)
and i am trying to solve exact it proplem. Binds works, but not like i am expecting

Comment: Why are you setting the `layoutX` manually, instead of using a [layout pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102) and configuring it to center the label?

Comment: actually i don't know. I have created the program for educational purposes, and now it last detaild of it. But if i will change way of realisation, anyway i want to know how do it

Comment: You simply shouldn't do this the way you describe. You should either use a predefined layout pane, or (advanced) you should create your own `Pane` subclass and override the various layout methods (particularly `layoutChildren()`). There is almost certainly an appropriate layout pane that does what you want.

Comment: You mean that each controll must have own Pane on main Pane? But what it will get me? any way i must setting alignment on this inner pane. Or not?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that comment. I mean you should use an appropriate layout pane, or combination of layout panes, that lays your controls out as you want them to be laid out. The tutorial I linked shows an example.

Comment: I have seen your example, but how i read in books, use SceneBuilder for make form it is not necessary. I mean that is not forbidden to create forms with controls right in application, i think. Or am i wrong?

  so, are you thinking that it impossible? (what i asked in question)

Comment: No, you either misunderstood what you read, or you read something incorrect. SceneBuilder is a tool for generating the FXML. The layout structure should be the same whether or not you use that tool. It's not impossible to do it the way you asked, it is just not an approach that will lead to maintainable code, and you should not do it in production.

Comment: in this book http://ebook-dl.com/book/438 author shows how to make form with controls. I don't understand why can't i do as him show? i understand that you recommend me follow the rules in generally but it my first complete java project, and i do it for myself

Comment: I can't read that book without signing up for something I'm not prepared to sign up for, so I can't comment on whether you have misinterpreted what is in there, or whether what is in there is just bad advice. If you hard-code the layout coordinates (whether in Java or in FXML, and if in FXML whether using SceneBuilder or writing the code by hand), then nothing will respond when the layout needs to change. The way to make it respond appropriately is to use a layout pane that manages the layout. You can use bindings if you want, but you would basically be reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to center a label is to use a layout pane and configure the pane and/or label so that it is centered. For example, if you wanted the label horizontally centered at the top of the layout (or a region of the layout), you might use a `BorderPane` as follows:

```fxml
<BorderPane>

    <top>
        <Label alignment="CENTER" text="A Label" fx:id="myLabel">
            <maxWidth><Double fx:constant="POSITIVE_INFINITY"/></maxWidth>
        </Label>
    </top>

    <center>
        <!-- other content ... -->
    </center>

    <!-- other BorderPane regions as required -->

</BorderPane>
```

All of the settings here can be made using Scene Builder, if you choose to use it.

Comment: thanks you, for it answer. Yes, it works, but i want to try be reinventing the wheel, for learn how it works :)

Comment: @Дмитрий To do that you should subclass `Pane` and override `layoutChildren()` and the various `compute...()` methods. I recommend you look at the source code for one of the layout panes, e.g. [`HBox`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/9/rt/file/c734b008e3e8/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.java)

Comment: for another Label i used follow code:  labelUp.layoutXProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty().subtract(labelUp.widthProperty()).divide(2)); - it make Label aligment on Center. Now i want to do same, but it should consider length of text of label. Can you recommend me how to do it by this way?

Comment: @Дмитрий I don't recommend using bindings to manage the layout; this is not really their intended use. If you do use bindings for this, I don't see why the code you posted wouldn't work.

Comment: i have added details in post. may bi it help you to understand me @James_D

Comment: @Дмитрий The reason it's not working in the code you posted is because you have a copy and paste error. In the key handler on the text field you bind the position of `chkL` based on the width of `labelUp`. But again, this is not a reliable way to do layout. Use a `VBox` with alignment set to center everything horizontally and vgap set to 18.

Comment: where do you see that chkL based on width of labelUp? it based on own width: chkL.layoutXProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty().subtract(**chkL.widthProperty()**).divide(2));  I didn't understand you. What am i copied and pasted? I understood that is bad way to control of Label, but i want to solve it by this way.

Comment: @Дмитрий Last line of the key pressed handler. I don't even know why you have a binding there in the first place.

Comment: Jesus Christ, i'm so stupid! I didn't see this line all that time! Thank you, and apologize me for i taked so much your time. How can i set your answer as answer of my question?